# How to allow users to create only one group using Organic Groups 7

Tags: organic-groups

I am trying to use OG7 to get users to create groups as companies - i.e., each group set up will be a company. I would like to to make sure that ea ch group admin can only create one group (i.e., her/his company); and the "add content>> group" link is disabled or not displayed once a company has been created.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Node Limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit) module to limit to one the number of nodes of your group content type to be created by user.